# Microsoft Powershell script running problem

Tags: powershell, office365

**I try to run following script:**

Get-ExecutionPolicy

$UserCredential = Get-Credential

Create session to: https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ with following:

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange
-ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential
-Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
```

**After I run the last script, it returns with following error:**

```
"New-PSSession : [outlook.office365.com] Connecting to remote server outlook.office365.com failed with the following err
or message : Adgang nægtet. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
At line:1 char:12
+ $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -Conne ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New-PSSession], PSRemotin
gTransportException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : AccessDenied,PSSessionOpenFailed"
```

Comment: `Adgang nægtet` is Danish and means `access denied`. Double-check that the credentials work.

Comment: Yes I know, and I have already assigned full rights to the user

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to connect to Exchange the module ExchangeOnlineManagement , you can use this:

```
$creds = (Get-Credential)
Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName $creds.UserName
```

I've also had success using this:

```
$creds = (Get-Credential)
$exoSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $creds -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection 
Import-PSSession $exoSession -DisableNameChecking
```